# Passing Data Between Two NSOperations

Tags: swift, nsoperation

I watched with a great attention the WWDC 2015 sessions about [Advanced NSOperations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-226/) and I played a little bit with the [example code](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2015/downloads/Advanced-NSOperations.zip).

The provided abstraction are really great, but there is something I may did not really good understand.

I would like to pass result data between two consequent Operation subclasses without using a MOC.

Imagine I have a `APIQueryOperation` which has a `NSData?` property and a second operation `ParseJSONOperation` consuming this property. How do I provide this `NSData?` intance to the second operation ?

I tried something like this :

```
queryOperation = APIQueryOperation(request: registerAPICall)  
parseOperation = ParseJSONOperation(data: queryOperation.responseData)  
parseOperation.addDependency(queryOperation)
```

But when I enter in the `execute` method of the `ParseJSONOperation` the instance in not the same as the same as in the initialiser.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: responseData is probably nil when you are constructing the ParseJSONOp. You probably want to pass through either the queryOp or an object that will hold the response so you can query `responseHolder.responseData` in parseOp when it starts

Comment: It is nil for sure. Are not Optionals reference type ?

Comment: Remember, your data object is Nil, meaning there is no pointer that can be used and retained for when it is populated...

Comment: Ok. So I should considerate Optional as reference type only if they are non nil ?

Comment: The idea of optionality has nothing to do with reference types. A reference type is simply an object that is passed by reference and not value. In this case you are not passing an object, you are passing nil:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is that you are constructing your `ParseJSONOperation` with a nil value. Since you have two operations that rely on this `NSData` object I would suggest you write a wrapper object to house this data.

To try and be aligned with the WWDC talk lets call this object the APIResultContext:

```
class APIResultContext {
    var data: NSData?
}
```

now we can pass this object into both the `APIQueryOperation` and the `ParseJSONOperation` so that we have a valid object that can store the data transferred from the API.

This would make the constructors for the query:

```
let context = APIResultContext()
APIQueryOperation(request: registerAPICall, context: context)
ParseJSONOperation(context: context)
```

Inside your `ParseJSONOperation` you should be able to access the data assuming the query completes after it sets the data.

#### Thread Safety

As @CouchDeveloper pointed out, `data` is not strictly speaking thread safe. For this trivial example since the two operations are dependent we can safely write and read knowing that these accesses wont take place at the same time. However, to round the solution up and make the context thread safe we can add a simple `NSLock`

```
class APIResultContext {
    var data: NSData? {
        set {
            lock.lock()
            _data = newValue
            lock.unlock()
        }
        get {
            lock.lock()
            var result =  _data
            lock.unlock()
            return result
        }
    }

    private var _data: NSData?
    private let lock = NSLock()
}
```

Comment: You require synchronisation primitives when accessing the `data` value from class `APIResultContext`. Otherwise, your approach is not "thread-safe". Additionally, you still need to setup the dependency.

Comment: Technically it is threadsafe since the operations are dependant one on another and so ParseOperation wont be accessing it before its written to. But valid point @CouchDeveloper

Comment: I beg to differ: the access to the member value `data` may be performed from different _execution contexts_  (Apple sometimes uses the term `Execution Environment`). These are not known at the call-site and are an implementation detail in the two subclasses of `NSOperation`. That is, actual, these may be different threads, different dispatch queues, or what ever. In Swift, there is no implicit synchronisation. Additionally, methods and functions are subject to be inlined and optimised in a way which makes the access unsafe with respect to concurrency.

Comment: Regardless of the execution context, operation 2 cannot possibly start before operation 1 finishes and writes to `data`. The only way this could happen is if operation 1 writes to data asynchronously and finishes execution immediately. @CouchDeveloper

Comment: @CouchDeveloper updated in the spirit of being Academically correct